# What is a good resource for learning about Molecular Gastronomy?

Tags: resources, molecular-gastronomy

Before frequenting this site I had never even heard of molecular gastronomy and now I am intrigued. Is there a good resource to learn about the process either web or in printed format that would be a reliable source of information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Khymos](http://khymos.org/) is a fantastic resource, and has probably [the best collection of recipes](http://blog.khymos.org/recipe-collection/) out there at the moment.

There's also a lot of good stuff at the French Cullinary Institute's [Cooking Issues blog](http://www.cookingissues.com/). They've got [a good post on hydrocolloids](http://www.cookingissues.com/primers/hydrocolloids-primer/) that's quite enlightening.

I actually disagree on the McGee recommendations. While it's an excellent book, full of great info, I don't think it's a good starting point for molecular gastronomy (in the sense of the cooking movement rather than the more literal sense)

Answer (score 4):

This very site. Take a look at the other questions tagged [molecular-gastronomy](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/molecular-gastronomy).

Of particular note is this [similar question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/6434/60) which has a [great answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/6434/60/#7751) by daniel.

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend [The Fat Duck Cookbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/160819020X) by Heston Blumenthal. He explains each recipe in detail and goes into the chemistry behind it as well. There is also [On Food and Cooking](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0684800012) by Harold McGee, which I think is the reference book to have.

The McGee book has its own Wikipedia article:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Food_and_Cooking

Answer (score 1):

Harold McGee's *On Food and Cooking* for a start.

Answer (score 1):

Hervé This' [Molecular Gastronomy: Exploring the Science of Flavor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0231133138) is a good choice if you are interested in the science behind molecular gastronomy. You may not learn much in terms of recipes or cooking techniques but it provides lots of short essays about the science behind cooking. Keep in mind about the bad translation though.